# How I can enable/disable CMFCRibbonButton object?

Tags: visual-c++

How I can enable/disable a `CMFCRibbonButton` object?

I see that it has a member `IsDisabled()`, but there is no function like `setEnable(BOOL en)`.

I saw that in the `ribbonBar` of Word, some of the buttons are disabled, so I think there must be a way to enable/disable `CMFCRibbonButton`.

Code example:

```cpp
CMFCRibbonBar ribbon;
pcat_home = ribbon.myAddCategory("&Home", IDR_RIBBONBAR_SMALL, IDR_RIBBONBAR);
CMFCRibbonPanel *ppanel = pcat_home->AddPanel("", 0, NULL);
CMFCRibbonButton *pb = new CMFCRibbonButton(PRINT_COMSETUP_MSG, "func1", hicon1, FALSE, NULL, FALSE, FALSE);
ppanel->Add(pb);
//...
// pb->setEnable(false);  // this not work , but I want to disable the button**
```

Comment: Try to provide some code of what you are doing. This helps us to understand what you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
Derive my class from CMFCRibbonButton  and implemented a function **setDisable** which set the protected variable **m_bIsDisabled** 
Also need to override copyFrom to  copy m_bIsDisabled  when object create dynamicly .

```
class myRibbonButton : public  CMFCRibbonButton
{
   DECLARE_DYNCREATE(myRibbonButton)

   public:
    myRibbonButton(){}
    myRibbonButton(UINT nID, LPCTSTR lpszText, HICON hIcon, BOOL bAlwaysShowDescription = FALSE, HICON hIconSmall = NULL, BOOL bAutoDestroyIcon = FALSE, BOOL bAlphaBlendIcon = FALSE):
        CMFCRibbonButton( nID, lpszText,  hIcon,  bAlwaysShowDescription ,  hIconSmall ,  bAutoDestroyIcon ,  bAlphaBlendIcon ){}
    void setDisable(BOOL b) {  m_bIsDisabled =  b; }
    virtual void CopyFrom(const CMFCRibbonBaseElement& src) override
{
     CMFCRibbonButton::CopyFrom(src);
     m_bIsDisabled =src.IsDisabled();
}

};
```